# Converting Javascript JSON to .NET integer array

Tags: c#, json

I was trying to pass json data to .net mvc controller. it seems like mvc automatically converted id and lastdatetime to correct format, but not int[] currentIds, anyone know why?

```
var jsonData = {
                "id": id,
                "lastDataTime": lastDateTime,
                "currentIds": [1, 2, 3, 4]
            };


public void Process(int id, DateTime lastDateTime, int[] currentIds)
{

}
```

Comment: Are you sure your array is correctly set up: https://www.json.com/json-array

Comment: Yes. the json structure should be correct. I manage to debug and reach to that point of Process. i can get id and lastDateTime but currentIds is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" ,
            data: {
                "id": id,
                "lastDataTime": lastDateTime,
                "currentIds": [1, 2, 3, 4]
            },
           dataType: "json",
           traditional: true,
           success: function(msg){
                       alert(msg)
                   }
    });


public ActionResult Index(int id, DateTime lastDateTime, int[] currentIds)
{

}
```

Comment: Sorry, i actually had my ajax setup as dataType : json.

Comment: I managed to debug and reached the controller's process.. but int[] currentIds is null.

Comment: no error, but the currentIds is null. suppose to get a list of integer array. I am using MVC 5

Comment: I also use MVC5... My code is .....public ActionResult Process(int id,DateTime? lastDataTime,int[] currentIds)
        {
            
        }$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"@Url.Action("Process", "Home")" ,
            data: {
                "id": id,
                "lastDataTime": lastDateTime,
                "currentIds": [1, 2, 3, 4]
            },
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        success: function(msg){alert(msg)}

Comment: i didn't set to traditional : true. what is this?

Comment: traditional: true stops jQuery from doing a deep serialization of your data. For example, if your params contained an array, traditional:true would prevent jQuery from handling it the way modern frameworks expect it to be handled.   Refer:http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/ .  traditional is used to serialize .. In my code if I delete traditional: true, int array is null.. Please put traditional:true

Comment: OK.. found the culprit, i am using type : "get"

Answer (score 1):

Simplify this problem and get the array working first, try this:

**View**

```
var myArray = ["1", "2", "3","4"];


$.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST", 
                    url: '/ControllerName/ActionMethod/',
                    data: JSON.stringify(myArray),
                    cache: false,
                    //dataType: "html",
                    success: ///            
})
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index(List<String> currentIds)
{
   ///
}
```

Debug this and check the list is populated then introduce the other objects.

Comment: Thx. found the culprit.